# MVVM Understanding the basics

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I was hoping someone could sort this out for me. im trying my hardest to stick to the MVVM pattern as much as possible. yes i understand that this is a pattern and not a frame work.

so far after reading this is the Impression that i have. please advise if this is the wrong approach.

My project is basically a WMI browser that stores favorite queries and run multiple queries against computers and then compare results.

The View:
Is basically the XAML portion of the project. here we would bind the controls to the Model View including itemssource selected items and anything else that is required.
So the View has no access to the model view, it does not store data or manipulate data inside the model view. it only bounds to observable collections inside the model view

The Model View:
Is where and event triggers happen from client interaction, IE: selection item change or clicking a button. the Model view then uses the data the the model has gathered arranges the data in a view able context for the view.

The Model:
Gets the data required for the end users and stores the data for when the model view requires it.

Am i even close to right on this ?

View - XAML / Control Styling / Control Creation

Model View - Data Organisation / Event management / Data Display Management

Model - Data Gathering / Remote Connections to Data sources.

Comment: Seems like you got it. You should try to keep you view model layer as thin as possible e.g every bit of "data organisation" you can move to an application service will give you more flexibility and less dependency in the future.

Comment: @MichaelLo Agreed. A view model is typically tied to a view. Having dependencies (other classes) that do the work of producing the data helps a lot with using the data in multiple views (or user controls) in your app.

Comment: Disagree with the above two comments.  Models are generally simple data-bearing objects which, by means of DataTemplate logic in the UI, convey information from the VM to the user.  Your VM should be a bridge between application logic and user interaction.  A command is run by the View, the VM interacts with (e.g.) a WMI library, results are gathered into Models that are set as property values on the surface of the VM.  The View sees these changes (DPs or INPC) and updates what the user sees.  The Aristocrats.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds fine as long as your ViewModel are not actually dealing with view (WPF-specific) code.

Think of ViewModels as technology-agnostic. In theory, you should be able to run your ViewModels in a console or Android application, therefore any references or dependencies on `System.Windows` (WPF-specific) classes is unacceptable in the ViewModel level.

Comment: okay so my situation is that i when a user clicks on a class IE Win32_OperatingSystem. the treeview loads availible properties/instances and methods into the treeview. how do i i generate these items without using new treeviewitem function in the code ?

Comment: @NewBee: `unacceptable` is a bit harsh.  Like desktop applications used to have to reference System.Web.dll in order to use framework caching classes, if you wish to use the dependency property system for its many advances or serialize to XAML, you have to reference WPF-related assemblies.  Caching was split from Sys.Web, XAML moved from WPF, and in future other subsystems may similarly be split off.  Simply referencing a part of the framework doesn't necessarily break MVVM.

Comment: @Will what I mean is the ViewModel must NOT be tightly coupled with UI stuff, and no [DependencyProperties don't belong in ViewModels](http://kentb.blogspot.com.ar/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html). What you talk about can be decoupled via patterns such as Dependency Injection or Service Locator or the like.

Comment: @HighCore: A blog post does not make law.  That's opinion, and, yes, DPs can be in view models.  Honestly, nobody is writing a VM designed to be in a WPF *and* Android app.  And, if there is one person in the whole world who actually is, that one person can react to his design requirements and ensure his VM does not extend DependencyObject.  But, seriously, if he has access to INPC in an Android app should he not have access to DOs?

Comment: @Will `"nobody is writing a VM designed to be in WPF and Android."` - Please have a look at [Cross Platform MVVM Frameworks](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross). And no, DependencyObject is a WPF-specific concept which does not belong in a ViewModel.

Comment: @Will not to mention DependencyObject has Thread Affinity which makes the VM impossible to work with. You're free to keep doing stuff `your` way, but don't pretend that's the `WPF` way.

Comment: @HighCore: Orthodoxy for the sake of orthodoxy.  As I stated, if your requirements preclude DPs, then don't use them.  If they do not, feel free to take advantage of what they offer.  And, no, DPs are not WPF specific.  Anyone with experience in WF knows this.  You also ignore my examples of how framework Cache classes were web-specific and XAML was WPF specific until they were moved out of "WPF assemblies".  I'll also make one last note that INPC properties were, essentially, thread-specific until Bindings were updated (auto invoke on UI). Again, that's requirements, not orthodoxy.

Comment: @Will again, You're free to keep doing stuff `your` way, but don't pretend that's the `WPF` way. and Yes, `System.Windows.DepedencyObject` has nothing to do with WF's `DependencyObject`, except the name. And I'm not about orthodoxy, whatever that means, I'm about being able to change the UI (XAML) completely without having to correct a bunch of horrible `txtLastName.Text = pepe;` stuff. That's why the VM should NOT be coupled to the UI.

Comment: It's worth noting that an MVVM view model is rather different from a MVC view model.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. was a little easier than first anticipated.

```
public class ParentNode
{
    public ParentNode() { }
    public string ParentNodeName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SubNode> AddChildNodes { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CheckBoxSubNode> AddCheckBoxChildNodes { get; set; }
}
public class SubNode
{
    public SubNode() { }
    public String SubNodeName { get; set; }
}

new ParentNode() { 
 parentnodename = "parent"
 addchildnodes = new SubNode() { Subnodename = "subnode" }
)
```

Then some random XAML binding to bind to the correct propertes and all was good.
My View Model still doesnt directly access the View. :)